# Disconnecting src_tbls connection in dplyr

Tags: sql, r, dplyr

Is there a way to force disconnection of a `src_tbls` object in `dplyr` similar to `RPostgreSQL::dbDisconnect`?

See for example:

```
> src_temp <- src_postgres(dbname = "temp", host = "127.0.0.1", port = 5432, user = "x", password = "y")
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (cannot allocate a new connection -- maximum of 16 connections already opened)
```

As a side note,  it does auto-disconnect quite quickly after a few seconds:

```
Auto-disconnecting postgres connection (3734, 26)
```

after which you can run the `src_postgres` command again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
RPostgreSQL::dbDisconnect(src_temp$con)
```

to force a disconnect.

That's what's called on garbage collection from this function in `dplyr` (via the `dbi-s3.r` source file):

```
# Creates an environment that disconnects the database when it's
# garbage collected
db_disconnector <- function(con, name, quiet = FALSE) {
  reg.finalizer(environment(), function(...) {
    if (!quiet) {
      message("Auto-disconnecting ", name, " connection ",
        "(", paste(con@Id, collapse = ", "), ")")
    }
    dbDisconnect(con)
  })
  environment()
}
```

Comment: In other words, you can just `rm()` old connections, and they'll go away on the next gc.

Comment: That is not happening for me: after `rm(list = ls())` I still get `Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : RS-DBI driver: (�p�_�cannot allocate a new connection -- maximum of 16 connections already opened)` when I try to open a new `dplyr::src_postgres(...)`.

Comment: @Dambo Now I just close and re-open the project. That takes care of it reliably.

Comment: @Gabi, since `dplyr version <= 0.5` uses  `RPostgreSQL` you can manually list, and remove connections by repeatedly spamming: `RPostgreSQL::dbDisconnect(RPostgreSQL::dbListConnections(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL())[[1]])` to the console. This may have unwanted side effects of removing connections you do want.

Comment: @Dambo see above.

Comment: The same works for RMySQL connection: repeatedly calling `RMySQL::dbDisconnect(RMySQL::dbListConnections(RMySQL::MySQL())[[1]])` disconnects all MySQL connections.